# How to replace string in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, string-interpolation

I have used with below interpolation in html page.

```
<div>{{config.CompanyAddress.replace('\n','<br />')}}</div>
```

and also used

```
<div>{{config.CompanyAddress.toString().replace('\n','<br />')}}</div>
```

But both are showing text as below

```
{{config.CompanyAddress.replace('\n','<br />')}}
{{config.CompanyAddress.toString().replace('\n','<br />')}}
```

Comment: Create a Pipe for that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use a pipe for the same:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'replaceLineBreaks'})
export class ReplaceLineBreaks implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  }
}
```

The pipe must be included in your @NgModule declarations to be included in the app.
To show the HTML in your template you can use binding outerHTML.

```
<span [outerHTML]="config.CompanyAddress | replaceLineBreaks"></span>
```

Answer (score 16):

`{{}}` is for string interpolation and the result will always be added as String. The binding doesn't work at all in this case because of the `<` and `>` contained in the expression, the `{{}}` are not interpreted as expected.

```
<div [innerHTML]="replaceLineBreak(config.CompanyAddress) | safeHtml"></div>
```

with

```
replaceLineBreak(s:string) {
  return s && s.replace('\n','<br />');
}
```

should do what you want. As mentioned by @hgoebl `replaceLineBreak` could be implemented as pipe as well if you need it at several places.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DTRSRrusxkp7bIeHHCbg?p=preview)

**Hint**: It's discouraged to bind to methods directly, because the method is called at every change detection cycle. A pure (default) pipe is only called when the input value changes. Therefore a pipe is more efficient.

Another way is to do the replacement only once and bind to the value with the replaced line breaks instead of calling `replaceLineBreak` repeatedly.

**Hint**: You probable want to replace all line breaks, not only the first. one. There are enough JS questions out there that explain how to do that, therefore I didn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an approach for replacing a sub-string in a variable in an angular template, but passing both the `substring` and the `replacement` by parameter to the pipe.

```
//TS
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
@Pipe({ name: "replaceSubstring" })
export class ReplaceSubstring implements PipeTransform {
  transform(subject: string, substring: string, replacement: string): string {

    //notice the need to instantiate a RegExp object, since passing
    //'substring' directly will NOT work, for example
    //subject.replace(substring, replacement) and
    //subject.replace(`/${substring}/`, replacement) don't work

    return subject.replace(new RegExp(substring), replacement);
  }
}

<!--HTML-->
<!--Example: remove a dot and the numbers after it, from the end of 'variable'-->
<!--Parameters in this case are "\\.\\d*`$" and "",
    you can pass as many as you want, separated by colons ':'-->

{{ variable | replaceSubstring: "\\.\\d*`$" : "" }}
```