# Amend end of API JSON return

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I currently pull some data from an API which in order to get an img url i have `{{item.smallImageUrls}}` this will return something like `https://www.someinslgknfld.co.uk/somgff.jpg?=s90` I need to change part of this url for every img that is returned under this phrase, specifically the `s90` which needs to be changed to a different value, `s300` for example.

Any idea on how i manipulate this data?

UPDATE

I have created a pipe of

```
  transform(value, args) {
    let replace = value.replace("s90", "s300");
    return replace;
  }
```

But i am getting the error of `value.replace is not a function`
This is similar to the rest of my pipies, only difference is that this is a image url instead of a string, any ideas?

HTML

```
 <div class="thumb">
   <img src="{{item.smallImageUrls}}">
 </div>
```

Returned JSON

[image]

Comment: how do you determine what to change the value to?

Comment: You can use a pipe to do a replace, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/41563283/1137729 and you'll get the idea